# Get the Nth row in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In MySQL I can do `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10`

In MSSQL I can do `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tbl`

How do I do this in Postgresql?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the [`LIMIT` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-limit.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl OFFSET 20
```

and, of course

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 8):

From the PostgreSQL docs:

```
SELECT select_list
  FROM table_expression
  [ ORDER BY ... ]
  [ LIMIT { number | ALL } ] [ OFFSET number ]
```

So LIMIT should work as it does in MySQL.  OFFSET is used to skip  rows before starting to return data.

See [docs for LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/queries-limit.html)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you quote for MySQL should work just fine for Postgresql as well. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Limit: How many rows do you want to see?

Offset: how many rows do you want to skip from the top?

For example, we want to see 9th-row records in my table.
the query will be :

```
select first_name from person order by first_name desc limit 1 offset 8;
```

[image: we want to see first_name of the 9th person only]

Comment: This is fundamentally no different than the [second highest rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082853/6951294) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR `SELECT * FROM your_table OFFSET N-1 LIMIT 1` where `N` is the row you want. E.g. Get 5th row:
`SELECT * FROM your_table OFFSET 4 LIMIT 1`